# Login and fetch a protected page with cURL

Tags: php, email, curl, remote-access

I got the login part of the script working however the second part does not work.

```
<?php

// Curl login
$login = "http://****/admin/index.php?route=common/login";
$credentials = "username=admin&password=****";
$cookie = "cookie.txt";

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $login); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $credentials); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$exec = curl_exec ($ch); 

// Logged in, fetch the post data
$url = $_POST['order'];
$return = $_POST['return'];

// Request the protected invoice page
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Mail it
mail('****@gmail.com', 'Invoice', $response, $headers);

// Dump it
    var_dump($response);
?>
```

Now If I provide wrong credentials then I am mailed the admin login page with login errors however if i provide correct credentials i simply get nothing back an empty email. `var_dump` at the end of the script returns `string(0)`.

The `$url = $_POST['order'];` is accessible and it's a correct url if logged in administration it returns the order invoice page.

Should I reinitialize curl after trying to fetch the protected page. So first login > close curl then reinitialize and fetch the page or did I miss some option ?

My reiteration:

```
<?php

    // Curl login
    $login = "http://***/admin/index.php?route=common/login";
    $credentials = "username=***&password=***";
    $cookie = "cookie.txt";

    // Initialize
    $ch = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $login); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $credentials); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1)
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6"); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);

    // Login - use 
    $exec = curl_exec ($ch); 

    // Logged in, fetch the post data
    $url = $_POST['order'];
    $return = $_POST['return'];

    // Request the protected invoice page
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    echo '<br /><br />-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------<br /><br />';
    var_dump($response);

    echo '<br /><br />-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------<br /><br />';
    var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch));

    echo '<br /><br />-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------<br /><br />';
    var_dump(curl_error($ch));

    echo '<br /><br />-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------<br /><br />';
    echo $url;

    echo '<br /><br />-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------<br /><br />';

    // Close the funnel
    curl_close($ch);

    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

    // Mail it
    mail('***@gmail.com', 'Predracun', $response, $headers);
?>
```

This is what I have now and it's throwing me a 500 error when I run the script.

Comment: Check that the url you're poking at doesn't do any redirects. Since you don't have a `FOLLOW_LOCATION` option set, curl will NOT follow redirects and simply return.

Comment: any change if you also add `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);` right after `curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);` ?

Comment: I still get string(0).. from var_dump()

Comment: @MarcB I added curl_setopt($ch, FOLLOW_LOCATION); right after curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); I still get the same error any ideas ?

Comment: sorry, it's `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`. all of the constants for curl options are CURLOPT_SOMETHING.

Comment: @MarcB Can you look at my code I changed my old code according to PHP/cUrl documentation however it's throwing ERR 500 now.

Comment: Do I need to first do the login part close curl then access the page or ?

Comment: The code looks ok, so start observing what's happening when a browser does the login sequence. it's often not enough to just duplicate the form fields, especially when javascript is involved. use a web traffic monitor, e.g httpfox in firefox, to see what's going out/in on the wire.

Comment: @MarcB I solved the 500 error it was the missing ; after FOLLOWLOCATION..